# RegisterArrayDeclaration with single element

Tags: javascript, .net, arrays, vb.net

I am registering a JavaScript array in the backend of my code.  On some occasions it is placing commas in the array instead of the actual values.

Here are two cases where I get different results:
oData Table 1:

```
statustype | orderstatus | ordercount
   6       |  received   |     6671
```

oData Table 2:

```
statustype | orderstatus | ordercount
   8       |  unknown    |        1
   4       |  pending    |      567
   3       |  in process |      117
   1       |  entered    |        3
```

```
Dim sOrderStatus As String = String.Empty
Dim iOrderCount As New List(Of Integer)
With oData

    If .Rows.Count = 0 Or sError.Length > 0 Then
        Response.Write(GetErrorNotFound())

        ddlWarehouses.Visible = False
        lblWarehouse.Visible = False
    Else

        For Each oRow In .Rows

            sOrderStatus = sOrderStatus & "'" & oRow.Item("OrderStatus").ToString & "',"
            iOrderCount.Add(CInt(oRow.Item("ordercount")))

        Next

        'Turn into array then register as javascript array
        Dim orderArray As Integer() = iOrderCount.ToArray

        For s = 0 To orderArray.Count - 1
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("orderArray", CStr(orderArray(s)))
        Next

        'Remove extra comma and register as javascript array
        If sOrderStatus <> String.Empty Then
            sOrderStatus = sOrderStatus.Remove(sOrderStatus.LastIndexOf(","), 1)
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("generatedLabels", sOrderStatus)
        End If

    End If

End With
```

Javascript:

```
alert("length: " + orderArray.length);
alert(orderArray.toString());
```

Result of 1:
    length: 6671
    [image]
Result of 2:
    length: 4
    [image]

**Edit:**
I've come across something interesting.  If I declare an integer array with multiple values in it, everything works fine but if I declare it with only one value the issue appears.  Is this a bug??

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After gaining some knowledge of JavaScript this must be because .NET is declaring the array with

```
new Array(*whatever you pass*);
```

With this syntax, if a single number is passed to the array constructor then it will generate an array of that length rather than with that element in it hence why I was getting an array with the length of the single number I passed to it.